# TryUpdateModel return false 'x' field is required

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner in asp.net MVC and everything was going fine until we start to call the controllers from front end project, we faced a lot of errors that make TryUpdateModel() return false, we find solution for all errors except one error that said 'contactId' is required. let me show you the structure of the model and the debug process:

- the structure of Company model contains company info and (contact, city) as objects and their foreign keys fields.

> first in company controller on create action we try to insert the contact object first to get the id and assign it to the company object as a foreign key and its successfully added and assigned the foreign key
> [image]

> then now we try to update the model but it's return false. NOTE that when it's return false the inserted contact object change it's id to 0 and I think that maybe cause an error.
> [image]

> at last this is the error and note that 'contactId' in company object still have the key value of the inserted Contact object.
> [image]

Comment: Please post code not image of code, take a tour on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you show your model because I think you have to remove [Required] from ContactId property and then check it out hope it will help you!

Comment: @Waleed I had a similar problem. But WHY does removing required from some of the properties fix this problem? I was not even requiring and `id` value, but just a less important field.